# Google Cloud Run or Cloud Function for one-time-task-job

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run

We have startup script that will create monitoring alerts using Google APIs.

For this we created a postman collection where we have bundled all these calls and then we wish to run a shell script where we will use service account json file and call the postman collection

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/home/abc/sac-5f63.json
export TOKEN=$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)
echo $TOKEN
echo "Running postman collection start"
newman run /home/abc/API.postman_collection.json
```

We created a docker file for this task with required dependencies and gcloud sdk as base image.

Now, We also want to give provision to execute this one time job in Google Cloud to users. For this we are considering options such as Cloud Run, Cloud Function, App Engine. But, all these services  expose an endpoint and then it has to be called and the the service will perform the action.

Our requirement is  a one time activity so we don't want to keep a service running all the time. Also, this is not a node js, java, go application that these services support.

It is  more like a one time job task, that should get trigger do it's job and then stop.

Does google cloud support such a use case. Basic hello world docker is an example of this kind of requirement that we have -
https://hub.docker.com/_/hello-world

We tried cloud run but it expects a portNo to be present with out which it fails

> Deployment failed
> ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) Cloud Run error: Container failed to start.
> Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT
> environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more
> information.

Please share some thoughts.

thanks,
Aakash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use [GKE Autopilot](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/autopilot-overview). You build your container and you run it, as pod job in your cluster. No need to expose a port or a webserver.

The first cluster is free on your billing account. You pay only for the CPU time and the Memory time of your running pod.

---

A dirty workaround is to use Cloud Build to run your container also, it's serverless, nothing to provision. It's not done for, it's a hack, but it works!

Comment: thanks we will check both GKE Autopilot and cloud build to get the container up and complete the job

Answer (score 0):

The hello-world container is not listening at any port port. That explains the error you got. Your container, must be listening for incoming HTTP requests as stated in the [Container runtime contract](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract). By default, Cloud Run requests are sent to 8080, but you can configure Cloud Run to send requests to the port of your choice.

So to be able to use Cloud Run as a solution, add a web server to your container.

Finally, keep in mind that the max timeout with cloud run is 1h.

Comment: thanks..it's a bootstrap task..so we don't want to spawn Webserver as it just needs to be run once..and again only if there is a special need later.

Answer (score 0):

Because your service may not support by cloud functions (check [functions-framework](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework)) or app engine standard natively, and also want the instances to scale down to zero, I think Cloud Run is for you.

The question becomes "how to invoke the Cloud Run service"

You can invoke either by events (firebase, gcs, pubsub...) or HTTP requests.
If you deploy the service as a HTTP service, you should listen to PORT environment, no matter what your program language (even in [shell](https://gist.github.com/upperstream/b9b77429bc024541b7605aea76086ad8)).

Answer (score 0):

Cloud function turned out to pretty useless us. Someone in Google thought of putting a 1 hour MAX container running time on Cloud Function jobs !